# How to group multiple list in a dictionary by category and word in python

Tags: python

I tried using itemgetter, but something seems to be wrong with my code..

```py
from operator import itemgetter

def create_dict(words):
    sorted(words, key = itemgetter category: category['food', 'animal', 'job'])


words = [('food', 'apple'), ('food', 'almond'), ('food', 'apricot'), ('food', 'beancurd'), ('food', 'bacon'),('food', 'bread'), ('food', 'beans'), ('food', 'broccoli'), ('food', 'cake'), ('food', 'chili'), ('animal', 'ape'), ('animal', 'ant'), ('animal', 'bat'), ('animal', 'bear'), ('animal', 'cat'),('animal', 'dog'), ('animal', 'flea'), ('animal', 'horse'), ('animal', 'lamb'), ('animal', 'leopard'),('job', 'baker'), ('job', 'farmer'), ('job', 'builder'), ('job', 'teacher'), ('job', 'pilot'), ('job', 'gardener'), ('job', 'gardener'), ('job', 'secretary'), ('job', 'salesman'), ('job', 'programmer'), ('job', 'manager')]

# *****FINAL RESULTS*****

create_dict(words) == {
'**food** ': {'apricot', 'cake', 'bacon', 'chili', 'almond', 'beancurd', 'apple', 'bread', 'broccoli', 'beans'},
'**animal**': {'dog', 'bat', 'horse', 'leopard', 'bear', 'ape', 'cat', 'flea', 'lamb', 'ant'}, 
'**job**': {'pilot', 'programmer', 'manager', 'gardener', 'farmer', 'teacher', 'builder', 'baker', 'secretary', 'salesman'}}
```

Comment: `create_dict(words) == {...}` will not work as the two `=`s will give you a `boolean` result. Your function `create_dict` also does not return anything.

Comment: You're talking about sorting, but your result if more like a grouping per 1st item

Comment: Hi azro, apologies i'm very new to python. I was thinking since I'm grouping then under a category, won't it be the same as sorting them according to the groups.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is absolutly not *sorting*, but *grouping*

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

words = [('food', 'apple'), ('food', 'almond'), ('food', 'apricot'), ('food', 'beancurd'), ('food', 'bacon'),
         ('food', 'bread'), ('food', 'beans'), ('food', 'broccoli'), ('food', 'cake'), ('food', 'chili'),
         ('animal', 'ape'), ('animal', 'ant'), ('animal', 'bat'), ('animal', 'bear'), ('animal', 'cat'),
         ('animal', 'dog'), ('animal', 'flea'), ('animal', 'horse'), ('animal', 'lamb'), ('animal', 'leopard'),
         ('job', 'baker'), ('job', 'farmer'), ('job', 'builder'), ('job', 'teacher'), ('job', 'pilot'),
         ('job', 'gardener'), ('job', 'gardener'), ('job', 'secretary'), ('job', 'salesman'),
         ('job', 'programmer'), ('job', 'manager')]

key = itemgetter(0)
result = {key: set(x[1] for x in values)
          for key, values in groupby(sorted(words, key=key), key)}
print(result)


{'animal': {'flea', 'dog', 'horse', 'lamb', 'leopard', 'ant', 'bat', 'cat', 'ape', 'bear'}, 
 'food': {'almond', 'broccoli', 'chili', 'cake', 'bread', 'beans', 'beancurd', 'apple', 'bacon', 'apricot'}, 
 'job': {'pilot', 'manager', 'gardener', 'teacher', 'secretary', 'baker', 'programmer', 'salesman', 'farmer', 'builder'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification azro, it make soo much sense now!

Comment: @EdwinEng You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the plain way, without `itemgetter`, by iterating through the tuples in your `words` list and adding the relevant items as another `list` to a dictionary.

**Input**

```
def createDict(words):
    outdict = {}
    for i in words:
        if i[0] not in outdict:
            outdict[i[0]] = []
        outdict[i[0]].append(i[1])
    return outdict


words = [('food', 'apple'), ('food', 'almond'), ('food', 'apricot'), ('food', 'beancurd'), ('food', 'bacon'),('food', 'bread'), ('food', 'beans'), ('food', 'broccoli'), ('food', 'cake'), ('food', 'chili'), ('animal', 'ape'), ('animal', 'ant'), ('animal', 'bat'), ('animal', 'bear'), ('animal', 'cat'),('animal', 'dog'), ('animal', 'flea'), ('animal', 'horse'), ('animal', 'lamb'), ('animal', 'leopard'),('job', 'baker'), ('job', 'farmer'), ('job', 'builder'), ('job', 'teacher'), ('job', 'pilot'), ('job', 'gardener'), ('job', 'gardener'), ('job', 'secretary'), ('job', 'salesman'), ('job', 'programmer'), ('job', 'manager')]

outdict = createDict(words)

print(outdict)
```

**Output**

```
{
'food': ['apple', 'almond', 'apricot', 'beancurd', 'bacon', 'bread', 'beans', 'broccoli', 'cake', 'chili'], 
'animal': ['ape', 'ant', 'bat', 'bear', 'cat', 'dog', 'flea', 'horse', 'lamb', 'leopard'], 
'job': ['baker', 'farmer', 'builder', 'teacher', 'pilot', 'gardener', 'gardener', 'secretary', 'salesman', 'programmer', 'manager']
}
```

Comment: That's a very interesting way to use ".append", never though of using it that way.

Comment: and the 5 lines of if/else could be `outdict.setdefault(i[0], []).append(i[1])`, then the final improvement is a `collections.defaultdict` ;)

Comment: Thanks @azro, you're definitely right on the appending the list once, after the if block and amended answer accordingly. I like your other inputs but I have not included them in my answer as I believe they're a bit of a trade-off with readability, which might be beneficial for Edwin at his/her stage, but I upvoted your comment so other readers may benefit from it. Cheers!

Comment: @EdwinEng the `.append()` method applies to `lists` and it is used to add an item at the end of a list. as `outdict[i[0]]` is indeed a list, in the above code it is used to add the items to it as the iteration progresses :) Check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for more method of the `list` data type.